# +server.ts Cannot find module './$types' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a +server.ts file where I'm using RequestHandler (per the docs). However - no matter what I do (re-created +server.ts, restart Svelte language server, restart TS server, run svelte-check, etc.) I cannot get `import type { RequestHandler } from './$types' to resolve.

My +server.ts file for development:

```
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types'
/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerData} */
export const POST = (async ({ clientAddress, request, url }: { clientAddress: string, request: Request, url: string }) => {
  console.log(request.body)
  try {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8787/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: request.body
    })
    if (!!res.ok) {
      const data = await res.json()
      console.log('data: ', data)
    }
  } catch(e) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Error: ', e }), { status: 500 })
  }
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Success' }), { status: 200 })
}) satisfies RequestHandler
```

My svelte.config.js file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter(),
    }
};

export default config;
```

My vite.config file:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite'
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $lib: '/src/lib',
            $routes: '.svelte-kit/types/src/routes',
        }
    },
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
})
```

It is also worth noting that I'm getting *another* error here:
`Cannot find module '@sveltejs/kit/vite' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

I've tried everything (cache clean, reinstall deps, etc) and I can't get this new sveltekit install to work properly.

Comment: Have you started the *dev server*, which is pretty much the only one that matters?

Comment: You mean `npm run dev`? I've restarted the dev server numerous times. Is there some special command that you're referring to?

Comment: The dev server runs the SvelteKit plugin which in turn generates the types referred to by `./$types`. But given that there are errors about other types being missing, probably is something else is wrong.

Comment: (`svelte-kit sync` should also generate the types just once.)

Comment: Yeah - I've tried all of that. I have ZERO clue what is going on. I followed the documentation to spin up the new SvelteKit installation. Something is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your +server.ts is inside the routes-folder.

I had the same problem and it was because I had placed the +server.ts in my /lib/api folder and not the /routes/api folder.